# Absolutely positioned element positions relatively to transformed element

Tags: css, css-position, transform, css-transforms

I recreated an issue that I am encountering in a template.
There is a **nav** that has `position: relative;`. Inside the **nav** there is a **div** with two lists nested.
One of the lists is position absolutely to stick to the bottom of the **nav**.
The problem occurs when the **div** has a transformation applied to it.
When the **div** in between the absolutely and relatively positioned elements get's a transform property, the absolute list positions itself relatively to the **div** instead of the **nav**.

[MDN Docs state the following about position:absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any,
>   or otherwise relative to the containing block. Absolutely positioned
>   boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any other
>   margins.

Does this mean a transformed element is a positioned element?
Why does it do this? I tested in Edge, FF, and Chrome. They all act the same.

You can run the recreated snippet below. I am applying the transform on the div on hover of the nav.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
nav{
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
nav:hover > div{
      transform: translateX(50px) translateY(0) translateZ(0);
}
a{
  color: #fff;
}
ul{
  padding: 16px;
}
ul.main{
  background: blue;
}

ul.lower{
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul class="main">
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="lower">
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know that I can solve it by changing the HTML, but I can't in the case of restrictions the template give me + I'm more curious towards why it is acting this way instead of a solution itself

Comment: Here is the same code on jsbin https://jsbin.com/covesawupu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I believe we can find an answer here: [MDN Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) ... it says: "If the property has a value different than none, a stacking context will be created." (in this case "the property" is referring to the transform property)... and here is some info about [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Comment: @CarlosMateo Yes, that seems to explain why it behaves this way. Thank you for the reference, this is interesting. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically because any element with the transform property applied, automatically triggers a new stacking order: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

"If the property has a value different than none, a stacking context will be created. In that case the object will act as a containing block for position: fixed elements that it contains."

Here is some extra info about stacking context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Stacking context doesn't have anything to do with it, that affects the z-index.   The correct answer is that it also creates a containing block.

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) for containing block

Answer (score 6):

The CSS spec states that [defining a `transform` on an element creates a **containing block**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering):

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value other than none for the transform results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block.

And that ([see spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#abs-pos)):

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with respect to its containing block.

---

The key here is that setting the `transform` property of an element to anything other thant `none`, creates a new **containing block**; *stacking contexts* have nothing to do with the way the element is positioned.

See examples in the below snippet.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 100px;  
}

.containing-block,
.stacking-context {
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.containing-block {
  background-color: hotpink;
  /* transform with a value other than none defines both a containing block and a stacking context. */ 
  transform: scale(1);
}

.stacking-context {
  background-color: orange;
  /* opacity with a value other than 1 defines a stacking context but no containing block. */
  opacity: .99;
}

.abs{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
    
  padding: 10px;

  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="containing-block">1: transform: scale(1);
    <div class="abs">1: Containing block example</div>
  </div>

  <div class="stacking-context">2: opacity: .99
    <div class="abs">2: Stacking context example</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the transform to `.main` instead of `div` it seems to work as expected.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to why it behaves this way, not how to solve it by changing HTML or CSS. Thank you for taking the time though.

Comment: Oh, ok. You only mentioned not changing HTML, so I thought this would work for you.