# Absolute element overflowing the document

Tags: html, css

I came across a strange issue while trying to position an `position: absolute` popup in my project.

Regarding `position: absolute` MDN says:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
>   created for the element in the page layout.

Unfortunately, in the example below positioning the element with `right: 0` and `transform: translateX(100%)` creates additional space outside the body as if the element were to be `position: relative`. This doesn't happen if we do `left: 0` and `transform: translateX(-100%)`.

```css
  .parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: magenta;
  }
  .child {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    width: 100px;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    right: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
```

Here's a link to an example of the issue https://jsbin.com/fikonusayi/edit?html,css,output

Is this a browser bug or is this an (un)expected feature?

*P.S. Discovered in Chrome and Safari.*

Comment: To add, this happens on right and not left because we're using a left to right, top to bottom system. Naturally, things can only overflow to the right or down.

Comment: Please add your [mcve] to the question itself; linking to a JSFiddle is not adequate per the rules.

Comment: PS you may find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39014650/2756409)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Your comment is not helpful.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks for the source. Updated the post.

Also, Interesting read about the transform matrix. However, I'm still confused about two things: 1) why the same effect can be achieved by removing `transform` and adding `right: 100000px` and 2) why this effect is not present with `position: fixed` ? Could you clarify please?

Comment: @TylerH how it answer the question? the transform is added to the absolute element not the parent element .. it's about overflow not containing block here

Comment: @saranc it does create extra space at percentages under 100%, i tried it at 25/50/75 and 90%..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is about `overflow` not document flow. If we refer to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow):

> Generally, the content of a block box is confined to the content edges
>   of the box. In certain cases, a box may overflow, meaning its content
>   lies partly or entirely outside of the box, e.g.:
>
> ...
>
> A descendant box is **positioned absolutely**, partly outside the box. Such boxes are not always clipped by the overflow property on their ancestors; specifically, they are not clipped by the overflow of any ancestor between themselves and their containing block
>
> ....

You may notice that there is no positioned element other than `child` so the [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) of the `child` will be the viewport. And the trick here is that the scroll bar is always added to the containing block starting from the left (horizontal scroll) or the top (vertical scroll) so any overflow from the top or the left will becomes inaccessible.

Here is an illustration to better see the issue:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: magenta;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation:move 3s infinite linear alternate;
}
@keyframes move{
  from {left:-100px}
  to {left:100%}
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see we have a scroll only when the element overflow on the left side. Same logic if we consider top/bottom

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: magenta;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation:move 3s infinite linear alternate;
}
@keyframes move{
  from {top:-100px}
  to {top:100%}
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And to confirm that your element is indeed removed from the flow, simply add content and remove the fixed height from the parent element and you will see that there is no space considered for your element:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: magenta;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation:move 3s infinite linear alternate;
}
@keyframes move{
  from {left:-100px;top:-100px;}
  to {left:100%;top:100%;}
}

body {
 margin:0;
 border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget maximus nibh. Nam non libero molestie, placerat lorem sed, congue arcu. Aliquam eu ultrices nisi, sed facilisis purus. Suspendisse sit amet tincidunt massa, varius tempor mi. Suspendisse semper finibus ipsum in varius. Maecenas id commodo mi, vitae molestie diam. Nulla a risus cursus, auctor ligula sit amet, vestibulum purus. In in turpis non mi auctor viverra porta ac magna.
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Unlike with `position:relative`:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: magenta;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation:move 3s infinite linear alternate;
}
@keyframes move{
  from {left:-100px;top:-100px;}
  to {left:100%;top:100px;}
}

body {
 margin:0;
 border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget maximus nibh. Nam non libero molestie, placerat lorem sed, congue arcu. Aliquam eu ultrices nisi, sed facilisis purus. Suspendisse sit amet tincidunt massa, varius tempor mi. Suspendisse semper finibus ipsum in varius. Maecenas id commodo mi, vitae molestie diam. Nulla a risus cursus, auctor ligula sit amet, vestibulum purus. In in turpis non mi auctor viverra porta ac magna.
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Why it doesn't happen with `position:fixed`? simply because there is nothing specified in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow). Here is all the cases where we have overflow:

> - A line cannot be broken, causing the line box to be wider than the
>     block box.
> - A block-level box is too wide for the containing block.
>     This may happen when an element's 'width' property has a value that
>     causes the generated block box to spill over sides of the containing
>     block.
> - An element's height exceeds an explicit height assigned to the
>     containing block (i.e., the containing block's height is determined by
>     the 'height' property, not by content height).
> - A descendant box is
>     positioned absolutely, partly outside the box. Such boxes are not
>     always clipped by the overflow property on their ancestors;
>     specifically, they are not clipped by the overflow of any ancestor
>     between themselves and their containing block
> - A descendant box has
>     negative margins, causing it to be positioned partly outside the box.
>     The 'text-indent' property causes an inline box to hang off either the
>     left or right edge of the block box.

Comment: Great! I am programming for 3 years and actually never have paid attention to overflowing. This case was new to me. Any architectural/semantical decisions you'd suggest to avoid/fix overflowing?

Comment: @RolandJegorov I don't think overflowing is an issue to start with ... in most of the cases it's intentional, especially for some kind of animation where we hide element and make them appear (used with overflow:hidden to avoid the scroll). But in case it's accidental you simply need to pay attention, there is no general rules but try to avoid fixed height, don't forget `box-sizing:border-box` when dealing with padding/border/width or height. with position:absolute/fixed make sure to correctly set the position, etc ...